# How to access Cypress data in the console

Tags: cypress

Below is a screen shot of Cypress 6.8 runner. I am interested in accessing the data printed in the console shown on the right.

In order to see this information within the browser window where tests are executed, you would open the developer tools and click a row. In the example, I had clicked row 8 which is shown by the purple pin and tooltip stating that "Printed output to your console".

**Is it possible to programmatically access to this same information printed in the console?** For example, could I get access to the *command*, *applied to* and any other information that might be logged. My understanding is this information only appears when clicking the row.

I would like to access this information using a custom plugin. Can you please provide insight into how this might be possible? I've been experimenting with the **plugins/index.js** module exports which provides access to `on`. But, at this time I don't have any meaningful code to share. I'm in the learning stage trying to determine if its feasible to access this information. Thanks.

[image: Cypress app]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of your spec or in `cypress/support/index.js` you can add an event listener which listens for `log:added`, ref [Catalog of Events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Cypress-Events).

```js
Cypress.on('log:added',  (logObject) => console.log(logObject))
```

This provides your callback a stream of the "log attributes" objects in the first parameter, which have a `console.props` property, which is what is printed when you click a line in the LHS Cypress log.

```
{
    "message": "http://example.com/",
    "timeout": 60000,
    "name": "visit",
    "type": "parent",
    "event": false,
    "id": 3,
    "state": "passed",
    "instrument": "command",
    "url": "http://example.com/",
    "hookId": "r2",
    "testId": "r2",
    "testCurrentRetry": 0,
    "viewportWidth": 1000,
    "viewportHeight": 660,
    "wallClockStartedAt": "2021-03-20T03:12:21.490Z",
    "chainerId": "chainer4",

    "consoleProps": {
        "Command": "visit",
        "Resolved Url": "http://example.com/",
        "Redirects": [],
        "Cookies Set": []
    },

    "renderProps": {},
    "totalTime": 218,
    "snapshots": [
        {
            "htmlAttrs": {},
            "body": {}
        }
    ],
    "ended": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steve Zodiac, this is very helpful information. I was too focused on the documentation regarding plugins that I didn't take notice to the Catalog of Events.